# "if (switch.isChecked())" statement makes my app crash

Tags: java, android, arduino

I'm making an app in which Bluetooth controls an Arduino car. I'm trying to get a switch to turn the motors ON and OFF (right now an LED), but when I run the app with the following code, it gets crashed.

```
if (on_off_switch.isChecked()) {
    command = "1";
    try {
        outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); //transmits the value of command to the bluetooth module
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    command = "10";
    try {
        outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I run the app without that code section, it runs just fine. But when I run it with the code, the app doesn't get start and the Logcat says:

> --------- beginning of crash
>   2018-11-10 14:22:36.570 3311-3311/com.example.btcar2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.btcar2, PID: 3311
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.btcar2/com.example.btcar2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.btcar2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7016)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

I don't know how to fix it. Please just write if you have a question that might help my situation, thanks.

Here is the rest of my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "00:12:12:24:06:48"; //MAC Address of Bluetooth Module
    private final UUID PORT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    Button bluetooth_connect_btn;

    String command; //string variable that will store value to be transmitted to the bluetooth module

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Switch on_off_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.on_off_switch);
        on_off_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.v("Switch State=", "" + isChecked);
            }

        });

        if (on_off_switch.isChecked()) {
            command = "1";
            try {
                outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); //transmits the value of command to the bluetooth module
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            command = "10";
            try {
                outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        bluetooth_connect_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_connect_btn);

        //Button that connects the device to the bluetooth module when pressed
        bluetooth_connect_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (BTint()) {
                    BTconnect();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    //Initializes bluetooth module
    public boolean BTint() {
        boolean found = false;

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) //Checks if the device supports bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device doesn't support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) //Checks if bluetooth is enabled. If not, the program will ask permission from the user to enable it
        {
            Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (bondedDevices.isEmpty()) //Checks for paired bluetooth devices
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please pair the device first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            for (BluetoothDevice iterator : bondedDevices) {
                if (iterator.getAddress().equals(DEVICE_ADDRESS)) {
                    device = iterator;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    public boolean BTconnect() {
        boolean connected = true;

        try {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(PORT_UUID); //Creates a socket to handle the outgoing connection
            socket.connect();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Connection to bluetooth device successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;
        }

        if (connected) {
            try {
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream(); //gets the output stream of the socket
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return connected;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add more of crash messages that appear in Logcat?

Comment: A complete stack trace might be helpful

Comment: I have edited it now, so you can see all of the crash messages

Comment: Considering this statement: `on_off_switch.isChecked()` Do we really have any method viz. _isChecked()_ in _**Switch**_ class in Android? Well, I think _**CheckBox**_ class does have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amjad Alwareh said, `outputStream` object is null. You can see that from this statement in Logcat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference

By putting this code

```
if (on_off_switch.isChecked()) {
    command = "1";
    try {
        outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); //transmits the value of command to the bluetooth module
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    command = "10";
    try {
        outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in `onCreate` you are attempting to perform some actions with Bluetooth module without making sure that you have a connection.

I don't know your design and what are you trying to achieve. But I can suggest to put code above in a separate method like this:

```
private void performAction() {
    if (on_off_switch.isChecked()) {
        command = "1";
        try {
            outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); //transmits the value of command to the bluetooth module
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        command = "10";
        try {
            outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it in `BTconnect()` if you want to make something right after connection is established:

```
    // code before
    if (connected) {
        try {
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream(); //gets the output stream of the socket
            performAction();  // call it here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Or call this method in `onCheckedChanged`

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Log.v("Switch State=", "" + isChecked);
    performAction();  // call it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`outputStream` is null , You must create a new object of it , like what are you doing in `BTconnect()` `outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();`